# C#, C++ - Unsafe Pixel Color Finder Loop

Tags: c#, c++, pixel, unsafe

I'm trying to get the color of a pixel using C# or C++. I have done this using GetPixel, but that is too slow as you may already know. So, I've been researching and would like to use unsafe code. Here are two links which I've been using code from:

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/617613/Fast-Pixel-Operations-in-NET-With-and-Without-unsa

http://www.techder.com/2013/03/high-performance-systemdrawingbitmap.html?m=1

Now, one major problem with the above codes, is that they both use bitmaps. I do not wish to use an image.

What I'm trying to do is make a loop that keeps scanning the desktop (yes, the desktop. Not an image) for a SINGLE pixel color at a fixed location (x: 800 y: 600). I've done this using GetPixel, but again, it's too slow, so I'd like to use unsafe or marshal.

I don't want to change the color of the pixel or anything like that, I just want to press a button, and have it scan my desktop for a pixel color at location 800,600.

If someone could please help with this I would forever love you. I've been stuck trying to edit code for days now, and would just love to see it work. I appreciate you taking the time to read this.

Thank you!

Comment: GetPixel is fine for a single pixel

Comment: It works fine, yes, but it's a bit too slow for my needs. It takes about 1200ms using GetPixel, but I need to be much faster (100ms or lower).

Comment: How many times are you invoking this to get 1200ms?  I've just done a simple `GetPixel` and timed it at around 20ms per execution.  Is that fast enough?

Comment: Yes, that is definitely fast enough, but are you sure it does what I'm asking? If so, thank you a ton! Also, I don't understand what you mean by "how many times am I invoking it".

Answer (score 1):

Here are a couple of ways to go about this from C#.  One is a C#-only solution, the other uses p/Invoke to access the GDI directly.

As to whether this addresses your problem... maybe.  The code below gives you two ways to fetch the color of a single pixel on the screen.  If that's what you want, then this works... but if you want to check multiple pixels, getting the data in bulk is probably going to speed things up.  That's where things like reading the pixel data as an array can really help.  For single pixel reads, this code is probably all you need.

---

First, a C# method courtesy of [Rosetta Code](http://rosettacode.org/wiki/Color_of_a_screen_pixel):

```
static Color GetPixel(Point position)
{
    using (var bitmap = new Bitmap(1, 1))
    {
        using (var graphics = Graphics.FromImage(bitmap))
        {
            graphics.CopyFromScreen(position, new Point(0, 0), new Size(1, 1));
        }
        return bitmap.GetPixel(0, 0);
    }
}
```

On my computer this runs in about 20ms per invoke, measured over 1000 invocations.

---

Second, the more complex but still instructive and interesting GDI method:

```
public static class Native
{
    [DllImport("user32.dll")]
    static extern IntPtr GetDC(IntPtr hwnd);

    [DllImport("user32.dll")]
    static extern Int32 ReleaseDC(IntPtr hwnd, IntPtr hdc);

    [DllImport("gdi32.dll")]
    static extern Int32 GetPixel(IntPtr hdc, Int32 nXPos, Int32 nYPos);

    public static Color GetScreenPixel(int x, int y)
    {
        IntPtr hdc = GetDC(IntPtr.Zero);
        int pixel = GetPixel(hdc, x, y);
        ReleaseDC(IntPtr.Zero, hdc);

        // Convert returned pixel value (0x00BBGGRR) to Color (0xAARRGGBB) format
        return Color.FromArgb(
                (((int)0xFF) << 24) |
                ((pixel & 0xFF) << 16) |
                (pixel & 0xFF00) |
                ((pixel & 0xFF0000) >> 16)
            );
    }
}
```

Interestingly I get about the same speed for this code - ~20ms per invocation over 1000 invocations.  The time is mostly spent in the `GetPixel` call, so scanning different parts of the screen with the same `hdc` doesn't appear to improve the speed any.

Comment: I now understand what you mean by 'invocations'. Since the pixel isn't already there when I press my button, I use an infinite or 'busy' loop to continuously poll until the pixel is found. That might be why i'm getting such horrible results, but I'm thinking that's the only way to do it. In VB.NET, I did something like this: Do Until GetPixel(hDC,800,600) = 12454848 - Loop. There was nothing in the loop, just a continuous loop until the pixel was found. Does that mean i'm constantly invoking the GetPixel method?

Comment: Yeah, that kind of loop is expensive.  You should put a `Thread.Sleep(10);` in there to stop it trying to consume all available CPU... although there are some delays inherent in dealing with the screen anyway.

Comment: Ok, I put Thread.Sleep in the loop. It helps with CPU usage a lot (from 80% to 24%, but the ms it takes to react are still similar, give or take 10ms lol.

Comment: I just found a website that would utilize the same code I'm trying to achieve. http://www.humanbenchmark.com/tests/reactiontime/ I press a button, and it constantly scans a specific area until that area turns to a different color. I'm trying to get as fast as reaction as possible. That's why I use an infinite loop, because I don't know when the pixel changes.

Comment: If you're trying to beat the clock on a reaction test, then sure.  Why would you though?  Proving that computers are faster than humans is pretty easy to do.  A quick JavaScript patch to the code would do a better job much more easily.

Comment: True, but I have no experience in JavaScript. ;) The second link I posted has code for unsafe lockbits. Now that you know what I'm attempting, do you think you could change it to just a loop that 'scans' for a pixel color instead of changing the bitmap ( i think that's what the code is doing anyway)?

Comment: Scanning the bitmap data only works for bitmaps, it won't give you the current state of the screen.  You'll have to re-acquire the screen data each time you want to check.  20ms per check isn't a big cost however.

Comment: Ahh, so GetPixel is as fast as I'm going to be able to get?